# What is the problem in useSelector() hook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I have a problem with my code.
I try to make a todo app, and I try to make a function to filter the completed and not completed missions.
I use useSelector() hook.
the problem now is that when I execute the completed function it works well, but when I return to execute all function, all the missions in the redux store is cleared.
What is the reason and how can I fix this problem?

**Redux Code**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import _ from "lodash";
let id = 1;

const initialState = {
  messions: [],
  filter: null,
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "messions",
  initialState,

  reducers: {
    addMession: (state, action) => {
      state.messions.push({
        description: action.payload.description,
        id: id++,
        finished: false,
      });

      state.messions.reverse();
    },

    removeMession: (state, action) => {
      _.remove(state.messions, (n) => n.id === action.payload.id);
    },

    checkMession: (state, action) => {
      let index = state.messions.findIndex(
        (mession) => mession.id === action.payload.id
      );

      state.messions[index].finished = !state.messions[index].finished;
    },

    completedMessions: (state, action) => {
      state.filter = action.payload.key;
    },

    allMessions: (state, action) => {
      return state.messions;
    },

    clearMessions: (state, action) => {
      state.messions.length = 0;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addMession,
  removeMession,
  checkMession,
  completedMessions,
  // notCompletedMessions,
  allMessions,
  clearMessions,
} = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

**My App Component Code**

```
function App({
  removeMession,
  checkMession,
  messions,
  addMession,
  completedMessions,
  allMessions,
}) {
  const localMessions = useSelector((state) => {
    const filteredKey = state.filter;
    const all = state.messions;

    const completedMessions = all.filter((mession) => mession.finished);

    const notCompletedMessions = all.filter((mession) => !mession.finished);

    if (filteredKey === true) {
      return completedMessions;
    }

    if (filteredKey === false) {
      return notCompletedMessions;
    }

    return all;
  });

  console.log(localMessions);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ handleDeleteMession, handleCheckMession }}>
      <Layout title={"To Do List"}>
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center ">
            <Col sm={3}>
              <SideBar
                handleCompletedMessions={handleCompletedMessions}
                allMessions={allMessions}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <Input handleAddMession={handleAddMession} />
              <Messions localMessions={localMessions} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Layout>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );

  function handleAddMession(m) {
    addMession({ description: m });
  }

  function handleCompletedMessions() {
    completedMessions({ key: true });
  }

  function handleDeleteMession(id) {
    removeMession({ id: id });
    console.log(id);
  }

  function handleCheckMession(id) {
    checkMession({ id: id });
    console.log(id);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    messions: state.messions,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    removeMession: (action) => dispatch(removeMession(action)),
    checkMession: (action) => dispatch(checkMession(action)),
    addMession: (action) => dispatch(addMession(action)),
    completedMessions: (action) => dispatch(completedMessions(action)),
    allMessions: () => dispatch(allMessions()),
  };
};
```

Comment: You should return state from `allMessions` reducer.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit confused between actions and selectors.  Your `allMissions` reducer does not make any sense.  Calling this will actually mess up your state and break your app, but it's not really clear to me what it's supposed to do.  I think it's intended to remove the filter?  In which case you want:

```
allMessions: () => {
   state.filter = null;
},
```

This will remove the `true`/`false` value of the `state.filter` property and allow your current selector function to work.